# Interpreting Negative Binomial Time-Series

Tags: r, time-series, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm working with time-series data for someone else that counts events related to emergency departments over a 48-month period during which closures occurred and would like to investigate the effect of these closures.  Measurements are either counts of events or a proportion at each time point.

Initially they requested that I use Prais-Winsten time-series regression which accounts for the auto-correlation between repeated measurements.  They have now asked me to perform negative binomial time-series on the count outcomes to check consistency between modelling approaches (I had originally suggested alternatives to Prais-Winsten such as GARCH or ARIMA models but they weren't interested).

I've now performed the requested analyses but am struggling to reconcile the results from the two methods with each other and would be very grateful of advice.

### Data

```
> dput(sample)
structure(list(relative.month = 1:48, value = c(2407, 2019, 2623,
 2443, 2043, 2605, 2623, 2365, 2822, 2558, 2144, 2601, 3034, 2878,
 2883, 1995, 2323, 2861, 2193, 2729, 2859, 3118, 2064, 2350, 1701,
 1665, 1848, 1428, 1371, 2043, 1218, 790, 1502, 1591, 1661, 2074,
 713, 1531, 1460, 1444, 1391, 1632, 1623, 934, 1718, 1217, 1439,
 1377), step = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), town = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 1)), .Names = c("relative.month", "value", "step", "town"), row.names =     c(NA, -48L), class = "data.frame")

## Pre and post Means
> group_by(sample, step) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE),
            sd   = sd(value, na.rm = TRUE))
  step     mean       sd
   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     0 2522.500 336.5390
 2     1 1473.792 334.4394

## Difference in means Before (0) and After (1)
> 2522.500 - 1473.792
 [1] 1048.708
## Percentage difference in means
> 100* (2522.500 - 1473.792) / 2522.500
 [1] 41.57415
```

A quick plot of the data....

[image: Time-Series plot]

### Prais-Winsten

Running a very simple Prais-Winsten regression with one step and accounting for auto-correlation...

```
## Simple Prais-Winsten Regression with 1-step
model <- reformulate(response   = 'value',
                     termlabels = c('step'))
pwr.1step <- panelAR(formula         = model,
                     data            = sample,
                     panelVar        = 'town',
                     timeVar         = 'relative.month',
                     autoCorr        = 'ar1',
                     panelCorrMethod = 'pcse',
                     rho.na.rm       = TRUE,
                     seq.times       = FALSE)
pwr.1step %>% summary()

Panel Regression with AR(1) Prais-Winsten correction and panel-corrected standard errors

 Balanced Panel Design:
  Total obs.:       48 Avg obs. per panel 48
  Number of panels: 1  Max obs. per panel 48
  Number of times:  48 Min obs. per panel 48

 Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
 (Intercept)  2524.55      59.99   42.09  < 2e-16 ***
 step        -1051.90      85.00  -12.38 3.05e-16 ***
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 R-squared: 0.7598
 Wald statistic: 153.1524, Pr(>Chisq(1)): 0
```

My interpretation of this is that the step results in a mean reduction in the number of observed events, of roughly (/mean) of 908 events, which isn't far off the differences in the means before (0) and after (1) which is 904 (or a reduction of 37.56%).

Including (relative) time as a co-variate to estimate the change over time...

```
## Simple Prais-Winsten Regression with 1-step and time as co-variate
model <- reformulate(response   = 'value',
                     termlabels = c('closure', 'relative.month'))
pwr.1step.time <- panelAR(formula         = model,
                          data            = sample,
                          panelVar        = 'town',
                          timeVar         = 'relative.month',
                          autoCorr        = 'ar1',
                          panelCorrMethod = 'pcse',
                          rho.na.rm       = TRUE,
                          seq.times       = FALSE)
pwr.1step.time %>% summary()
Panel Regression with AR(1) Prais-Winsten correction and panel-corrected standard errors

 Balanced Panel Design:
  Total obs.:       48 Avg obs. per panel 48
  Number of panels: 1  Max obs. per panel 48
  Number of times:  48 Min obs. per panel 48

 Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
 (Intercept)     2526.3522    97.9934  25.781  < 2e-16 ***
 step           -1048.3859   172.1547  -6.090  2.3e-07 ***
 relative.month    -0.1453     6.2160  -0.023    0.981
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 R-squared: 0.7596
 Wald statistic: 152.9394, Pr(>Chisq(2)): 0
```

As with the simpler model there is still a reduction in number of events after the step, but inclusion of the time variable suggests that across the whole time series (i.e. both before (0) and after (1)) there tends to be a reduction in the number of events over time, although this is more obvious after the step.

### Negative-Binomial Time-Series

Running a negative-binomial time-series on the very simple model with just one step, but allowing for correlation between sequential observations....

```
## Negative Binomial Time-Series with 1-step
> outcome <- sample[,'value']
> covariates <- dplyr::select(sample, step)
> negbin.1step <- tsglm(ts    = outcome,
                        link  = 'log',
                        model = list(past_obs = 1),
                        xreg  = covariates,
                        distr = 'nbinom')
> negbin.1step %>% summary()
 Call:
 tsglm(ts = outcome, model = list(past_obs = 1), xreg = covariates,
     link = "log", distr = "nbinom")

 Coefficients:
              Estimate  Std.Error  CI(lower)  CI(upper)
 (Intercept)    8.3258     1.0195      6.328     10.324
 beta_1        -0.0629     0.1301     -0.318      0.192
 step          -0.5715     0.0888     -0.746     -0.397
 sigmasq        0.0349         NA         NA         NA
 Standard errors and confidence intervals (level =  95 %) obtained
 by normal approximation.

 Link function: log
 Distribution family: nbinom (with overdispersion coefficient 'sigmasq')
 Number of coefficients: 4
 Log-likelihood: -351.8314
 AIC: 711.6627
 BIC: 719.1476
 QIC: 3760.517
## Exponentiate the coefficients to obtain a percentage change
> negbin.1step %>% coefficients() %>% exp()
 (Intercept)       beta_1         step
 4128.9061822    0.9389960    0.5646913
```

Having read through the [tscount vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tscount/vignettes/tsglm.pdf) I take this to mean that there is (roughly) a 44% reduction in the observed number of events each month after the step, and that there is a small (~7%) reduction in the number of events over time (the `beta_1` coefficient).

Adding in time as co-variate to match the Prais-Winsten regression gives...

```
## Negative Binomial Time-Series with 1-step and time
> outcome <- sample[,'value']
> covariates <- dplyr::select(sample, step, relative.month)
> negbin.1step.time <- tsglm(ts    = outcome,
                             link  = 'log',
                             model = list(past_obs = 1),
                             xreg  = covariates,
                             distr = 'nbinom')
> negbin.1step.time %>% summary()
 Call:
 tsglm(ts = outcome, model = list(past_obs = 1), xreg = covariates,
 link = "log", distr = "nbinom")

 Coefficients:
                  Estimate  Std.Error  CI(lower)  CI(upper)
 (Intercept)      8.335323    1.04206    6.29292   10.37773
 beta_1          -0.063606    0.13211   -0.32255    0.19533
 step            -0.563206    0.12753   -0.81316   -0.31325
 relative.month  -0.000357    0.00412   -0.00843    0.00771
 sigmasq          0.035660         NA         NA         NA
 Standard errors and confidence intervals (level =  95 %) obtained
 by normal approximation.

 Link function: log
 Distribution family: nbinom (with overdispersion coefficient 'sigmasq')
 Number of coefficients: 5
 Log-likelihood: -351.7691
 AIC: 713.5383
 BIC: 722.8943
 QIC: 3923.615

> negbin.1step.time %>% coefficients() %>% exp()
  (Intercept)         beta_1           step relative.month
  4168.5475445      0.9383745      0.5693807      0.9996430
```

There is roughly the same reduction at the step, and given the correlation over time of a slight reduction (the `beta_1`) the `relative.month` co-variate shows virtually no change over time.

### Questions

1. Equivalence - the results are telling me roughly the same thing, that there is a reduction in the number of events caused by the step, and over time there is a reduction  in the number of events.
2. Is it reasonable to interpret the `beta_1` component in the Negative Binomial as being roughly equivalent to the effect of relative month, given that its estimating the correlation between sequential pairs of observations?  If so is there no need to include `relative.month` as a co-variate in negative-binomial time-series?
3. Is it reasonable to use a Negative-Binomial Time-Series model when the number of observed events are in the thousands?  Its been suggested that doing so might not be appropriate as negative-binomial distributions are for counts when there is over-dispersion (i.e. high-variance because of possible skewness).
4. Leading from the previous question, which approach is the most appropriate to report?

---